# Trying to understand uniqueness of group homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to understand an assumption of a solution we were given that was not proved:

Why is a group homomorphism $$\phi : \mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}, a,b \in \mathbb{N}, a,b \geq 2$$ uniquely determined by where $\phi(1)$ maps to?

It is obviously that $\phi(0) = 0$, but what about the other values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it must be that $\;\phi(\overline n+\overline m)=\phi(\overline n)+\phi(\overline m)\;,\;\;\forall\,\overline n,\overline m\in\Bbb Z/a\Bbb Z\;$ , and

$$\begin{cases}\overline n= n\cdot\overline 1\pmod a\\{}\\\overline m= m\cdot\overline 1\pmod a\end{cases}\;\;\implies\;\; \phi\overline(n)=\phi(n\cdot\overline 1)=n\phi\overline(1)$$

and thus the value of the homomorphism of any element of $\;\Bbb Z/a\Bbb Z\;$ is uniquely and completely determined by $\;\phi(\overline1)\in\Bbb Z/b\Bbb Z\;$ .

Answer (score 2):

$$\phi\left(\bar{n}\right)=\phi\left(\bar{1}+\cdots+\bar{1}\right)=\phi\left(\bar{1}\right)+\cdots+\phi\left(\bar{1}\right)$$